# Mobile Redirect Issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

So i have been trying to create a mobile redirect for a portion (service area) of my site. The way the site is built requires me to use the htaccess file to accomplish this. I have the code in and for some reason any visitors coming from Google AdWords or Map Listings are forwarded to the mobile site, whether or not they are on mobile/desktop. This is the only case i have an issue. 
My thought was to create a redirect back to the standard site from the mobile site for non-mobile visitors. Will this create a loop or will this actually work? Also how would the code work to designate, if NOT mobile, redirect to specific page. Here is what i have:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile-homepage$ http://www.example.com/homepage [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get rid of all the `OR` flags in your conditions. You don't want "Not A" or "Not B" (because then only B would make conditions true), you want "Not A" *AND* "NOt B"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie- [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile-homepage$ http://www.example.com/homepage [L,R=302]
```

The only questionable bit is the first condition. There's not way to logically group that OR everything else.